# Grails: How to use JNDI datasource in resources.groovy file.

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, jndi

I have defined Spring JDBC template in resources.groovy file as given below:

```
jdbcTemplate(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate) {
    dataSource = ? // Here I need get the datasource from JNDI
}
```

I need to get the datasource from JNDI and inject it to datasource property of spring template.

PS: Grails version: 2.4.4

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use the jdbcTemplate? If you set up your dataSource in DataSource.groovy, you can use JNDI there. Ex:

```
environments {

development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = false // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect...
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/YourDataSource"
    }
```

You will also probably need to add a resource-ref in your src/templates/war/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/YourDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

With the dataSource defined, the jdbcTemplate in resources.groovy should probably auto-wire it, or if it doesn't, make it:

```
jdbcTemplate(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate) {
    dataSource = ref('dataSource')
}
```

Hope that helps!